# Tried to convert 'n' to a tensor and failed. Error: None values not supported

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

I've hit my depth with this one and can't seem to get this (what would seem) simple linear regression to work. I know the answer is probably staring me in the face, but I think I've been staring at this to long to see it :).

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 510, in _apply_op_helper
    preferred_dtype=default_dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1022, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 233, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 212, in constant
    value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 401, in make_tensor_proto
    raise ValueError("None values not supported.")
ValueError: None values not supported.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 524, in _apply_op_helper
    values, as_ref=input_arg.is_ref).dtype.name
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1022, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 233, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 212, in constant
    value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 401, in make_tensor_proto
    raise ValueError("None values not supported.")
ValueError: None values not supported.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "flights.py", line 143, in <module>
    regressor.train(input_fn=training_input_fn, steps=10000)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 314, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 740, in _train_model
    input_fn, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 603, in _get_features_and_labels_from_input_fn
    result = self._call_input_fn(input_fn, mode)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 694, in _call_input_fn
    return input_fn(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/inputs/pandas_io.py", line 110, in input_fn
    features = queue.dequeue_many(batch_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/data_flow_ops.py", line 475, in dequeue_many
    self._queue_ref, n=n, component_types=self._dtypes, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_data_flow_ops.py", line 2445, in _queue_dequeue_many_v2
    component_types=component_types, timeout_ms=timeout_ms, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 528, in _apply_op_helper
    (input_name, err))
ValueError: Tried to convert 'n' to a tensor and failed. Error: None values not supported.
```

Code: https://pastebin.com/M9arSCQa

Data file: https://storage.googleapis.com/stackquestion2/201701.csv

**UPDATE**
After applying some of the suggestions the error has changed, however, the error was something I ran into prio this post, which means I'm running around in circles :)

Here's the complete error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError: FIFOQueue '_0_enqueue_input/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 128, current size 0)
     [[Node: fifo_queue_DequeueUpTo = QueueDequeueUpToV2[component_types=[DT_INT64, DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_DOUBLE, DT_STRING, ..., DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](enqueue_input/fifo_queue, fifo_queue_DequeueUpTo/n)]]
```

Latest code: https://pastebin.com/TvCw0rVw

Comment: From the looks of it, your datasource has "Null" entries in rows such as lines 331, 373 etc. When you read the file in pandas, it converts it to `NaN` but I don't see you replacing those values. So from what I can tell, they get passed on ahead as `None`. Of course, that's what it seems from a high level glance. So trying something maybe like `df.fillna("<filler>", inplace=True)` might resolve the issue?

Comment: I should have mentioned that this was one of the troubleshooting steps I took while debugging. I must have removed it from the source I uploaded. Anyways, I tried filling all none values with fillna and it didn't seem to change the error at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think your problem is here,

```
training_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x=training_data, y=training_label, batch_size=None, shuffle=True, num_epochs=None)
```

You `re setting batch_size to None, which ovverides the default parameter(128)  and when it reaches deque, it checks that parameter. Just remove the batch_size or set it to number that is a factor of your train size

Comment: This was another troubleshooting step I took while debugging, and setting the batch size to 64 or 128 return the same error: "tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Unable to get element as bytes"

full pastebin: https://pastebin.com/wdCQFkLk

Comment: could you check and run one example only,just to make sure you re not the dataset is correct, atleast we can remove the assumption that the dataset isn't the problem

Comment: checking at yourt dataset, line 331, 376,377 have some empty cells, i think you should also consider using fillna(use zero in case of numeric value)

Comment: Unfortunately no, dice... Filled in all zeros, limited things to 5 rows of data, and back to the original error: "tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Unable to get element as bytes."  Here's a pastebin of the altered code https://pastebin.com/8DmmW0dM

Comment: So this error `ValueError: Tried to convert 'n' to a tensor and failed. Error: None values not supported` no longer exists, yes?
And if so, is it possible to provide the full error message?

Comment: Full latest error: OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): FIFOQueue '_0_enqueue_input/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 128, current size 0)
  [[Node: fifo_queue_DequeueUpTo = QueueDequeueUpToV2[component_types=[DT_INT64, DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_DOUBLE, DT_STRING, ..., DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](enqueue_input/fifo_queue, fifo_queue_DequeueUpTo/n)]]

Comment: This looks promising at least, we are now sure that deque is getting nothing, so the problem is  in how our input_fn is being passed,that exception occurs when you request more than available dataset using most an iterator, isn't pd function x={'x':train_data} , rather than x:train_data in some of your agruments in input_fn or panda_related_fn, sorry , I am using my phone,I can't type correctly

Comment: i can't really find the error, but i would advise to print the input functon also before feeding it to dnn and linear regressor and keep the batch_size to 1 as debug mechanisim,from what i see here, categorical features are first put in buckets, but i think this would be related to dnn only https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/tutorials/wide_and_deep

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I tried what you mentioned, but ultimately It came down a combination of the data itself, the datatypes being called, and the labels I was selected for training. I eventually just started from scratch using sklearn instead, which helped me realize what was going wrong. Now, I'll work on implementing in tensorflow :)